# Question about empirical distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

The paragraph below is from the book Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R
Book by Christian Robert and George Casella page 23-24.

> For readers unfamiliar with the notion of the bootstrap, we briefly recall
> here that this statistical method is based upon the notion that the empirical
> distribution of a sample $X_1, . . . , X_n$ converges in n to the true distribution.
> (The empirical distribution is a discrete distribution that puts a probability
> 1/n on every point Xi of the sample and 0 everywhere else.) The bootstrap
> procedure then uses the empirical distribution as a substitute for the true
> distribution to construct variance estimates and confidence intervals. Given that the empirical distribution has a finite but large support made of $n^n$
> points, Monte Carlo approximations are almost always necessary to evaluate
> those quantities, as illustrated in the next example.

I don't understand " the empirical distribution has a finite but large support made of $n^n$
points" Where does  $n^n$ come from?

Comment: If you sample $a$ times *with replacement* from $b$ equally likely possibilities, then there are $b^a$ equally likely ways of doing this, taking order into account.  In the bootstrap $a=b=n$, the size of the original sample.

Comment: Can I interpret this way? In the context of the bootstrap, where $a = b = n$ (the size of the original sample), we are essentially creating a new (resampled) dataset which the size is now becoming $n^n$.